# Are indexes cheaper in NoSql (Mongodb) compare to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, json, mongodb

In our project, we are storing 'Product catalog' JSON in SQL database. This JSON contains multiple key-value pairs. This JSON is dynamic in nature since there could be many permutations and combinations of key-value.
We did not have to parse this JSON till now.
But now, we have a requirement where we would have to parse and select a product based on Key-value. These key-value pairs will be approx 40 in count.

Generally, We do not think of making indexes on 40 columns in SQL server (especially on transaction table). But if we move this data to NoSQL server (MongoDB) for instance, and store this JSON in dictionary/documents, it will automatically create the indexes on all of the items.

Wouldn't this slow down the insertion or 'Indexes are cheaper in NoSQL compare to SQL.'? Or they are implemented differently there?

Comment: we should not rush to downvote a question, to improve the effectiveness of this forum,  we can ask to edit the questions if it does not sound logical.

Answer (score 0):

Following link has a very good explanation about 'how Indexes are managed in Documentdb'. This is not a generic implementation across the NoSql, but this gives a very good understanding.
http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf